# Change line spacing inside a node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, line-spacing

Inside a TikZ node, one can force line breaks using `\\` providing the `align` option of the node is set.

I would like to increase the line spacing inside a node. This can be done in the usual way with the optional parameter of `\\`, e.g. `\\[1em]`. Doing this for every line break is tedious though. Is there a way to increase the break *globally*, so that any `\\` inside a node acts as `\\[1em]`?

EDIT: Almost there!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={
    draw
  , align=center
  , execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{2em}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] {
    this \\
    is \\
    \tikz \node[mynode] {a \\ break};
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Node breaks]

The remaining question is how to place a 2em break before the inner node.

Comment: Remark: it might be better to specify *vertical* distances in terms of ex's, not em's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about this?

```
\setlength{\baselineskip}{16pt}
```

or

```
\baselineskip=16pt
```

(If it doesn't work, try ending your node text with an explicit `\par`.)

Now as for the second part: this is not only non-trivial, but also not well-defined.  As the name suggests, `\baselineskip` is the distance between the *baselines of consecutive lines of text* (or hboxes, if you prefer).  In the case of the "inner" tikz node, there's the question: where its baseline is located?  This is configurable by the tikz option `baseline` (this was hard to guess, right;)?), but if you set it *higher*, then - if you add another line or whatever *below* - the distance there will be to small.

Probably the best answer to your problem are the `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` parameters.  Actually (well, AFAIR, since I've got my copy of The TeXbook at my office), the rule is (more or less) as follows:

> if TeX puts two boxes on a vertical list, it puts glue between them so the distance between *their baselines* equals `\baselineskip`.
>   But, if the distance between the *bottom* of the upper box and the *top* of the lower one would be smaller than `\lineskiplimit`, the glue inserted equals `\lineskip`.

Therefore you might want to set it up the following way:

```
\baselineskip=<the distance you want between the baselines>
\lineskiplimit=<the threshold distance>
\lineskip=<the distance you want between the boxes (not their baselines!) if they are close to each other>
```

where "close to each other" means "closer than the threshold".

Comment: length macros need \ (aka escape character) but counter macros do not. I also did the same mistake often in the past. :-)

Comment: @xport: This is because `\baselineskip` is a length defined by TeX itself. On the other hand if you create a counter by `\newcounter{name}` (a LaTeX command) this actually to the TeX `\newcounter\c@name` plus initializing plus creating the `\thename` macro.

Comment: xport: thanks for correcting me!
Caramdir: thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Where in the document to place `\baselineskip=16pt` and `\setlength{\baselineskip}{16pt}`